# Derivation of formulas for Boltzmann machines - MCMC

Tags: neural-networks, markov-chain-montecarlo

With interest i read the latest post on https://theclevermachine.wordpress.com/ on Boltzmann machines, and the derivation of the underlying formulas. The derivation (per below) shows that the derivative of the loss function is equal to $-E_{p(h|v)}\frac d{d\theta}E(v,h)$ + $-E_{p(v`,h`)}\frac d{d\theta}E(v`,h`)$

Then the text describes how one can approximate this by a MCMC calculation. Can anyone share the intuition why the specific sampling approach gives the expected values of interest?

[image]